# Swift How to change button label outside IBaction?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this IBAction button with title change functionality. How can I set the initial title from outside of IBAction?

```
@IBAction func startButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

if sender.currentTitle == "Start" {
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        start()
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a reference to the initial button (`@IBOutlet`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a reference to the button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

Then you can simply set the title in e.g. `viewDidLoad()` or wherever and whenever you want:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   myButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
}
```